# Как правильно передать переменную в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Требуется из `dropdownlist` удалить значение, `id dropdown` - динамический и пишется в переменную. Как передать переменную в `jQuery`?

```
var myString = "Status_10fc97a2-de77-438f-9896-bd129c153849_$DropDownChoice";
$("#"+myString+" option[value='test']").remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myString = "Status_10fc97a2-de77-438f-9896-bd129c153849_$DropDownChoice";
myString.replace(/\$/g, '\\$');
$("#"+myString+" option[value='test']").remove();
```